# Como criar notificações?

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Estou fazendo aplicativos somente para testar algumas funções para o Android e gostaria de saber como criar notificações na barra de status.

Meu código de Java e um código padrão que só chama o arquivo XML:

```
package com.bandicootapps.nav;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.webkit.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
   } 
}
```

Com o que eu complemento para quando o aplicativo for iniciado uma notificação seja criada? Gostaria também que tivesse um ícone nessa notificação.

Comment: A documentação tem um [guia](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) completo. Também pode ver as inúmeras perguntas já feitas aqui, pesquisando pela tag [`android-notification`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-notification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Exemplo:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
           new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
           .setContentTitle("My notification")
           .setContentText("Hello World!");

       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
       int mNotificationId = 001;

       NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
           (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
   }
}
```

**Referências e mais informações em:**

[Google Developers - Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

[Google Developers - Building a Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um exemplo simples que uso:

```
/* @param id identificacao da notificacao 
* @param title titulo da notificacao
* @param message mensagem a ser exibida
* @param intent se quiser uma tela que ser invocada quando clicar na notificacao*/

    public static void onCreateNotify(Context context, int id, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, Intent intent ) {

//          intent.putExtra(key, valueKey);

       PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Constantes.SUCESS, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

       NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_evendas_att)
               .setContentTitle(title)
               .setContentText(message)
               .setAutoCancel(true)
               .setContentIntent(pIntent)
               .setVibrate(new long[]{ 100, 250, 100, 500 })
               .setLights(100, 500, 100);

       NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());

    }
```

mas detalhes [aqui](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)